# how do I kill a node.js process from another node.js process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, batch-file, child-process

I'm trying to run scripts/node.js processes from another node.js processes. I figured out how to start them with `child_process.spawn()` and I have the PID from it but i can't figure out how to kill them. Using `child_process.exec()` to run `taskkill` with doesn't work even with`/F`, even though it says the "task-killing" was successful, the node.js window is stil running. I've even tried powershell's `stop-process` but that doesn't work either. How do I kill it? (from node.js)

Edit:

Both `process.kill(pid,15)` and `process.kill(pid,9)` end with:

> Error: kill ESRCH errno: -4040,code: 'ESRCH',syscall: 'kill'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS has a method called `kill` in the global `process` object, `kill` takes a `PID` (process id) and an optional `SIGNAL` (kill signal) to send to the process identified by `PID`.

This is how to use it

`process.kill(pid, SIGNAL)` -> SIGNAL is optional.

Assuming the process id is 1000

`process.kill(1000)`, not specifying a signal automatically sends [SIGTERM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTERM) to process id 1000.

It should be noted that `SIGNAL` can also be a number, the number value for `SIGTERM` is `15`. [SIGNAL NUMBERS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm)

For example, you can do this.

`process.kill(1000, 15)` or `process.kill(1000, 'SIGTERM')`  -> sends a terminate signal to process id 1000

`process.kill(1000, 9)` or `process.kill(1000, 'SIGKILL')` -> sends a  kill signal to process id 1000

[Documentation on process.kill](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processkillpid-signal).

When `pid` does not exists, the nodejs process will throw `ESRCH`.

Comment: Tried, both end with the same error. post edited.

Comment: @Mpkkle you got that error because the `pid` you are trying to kill does not exists

Comment: I created the process with `const proc = child_process.spawn(node, {detached: true})`, then i got the process id with `proc.pid`. when i was trying it i tried to kill it right after i spawned it. i even tried `get-process` with the pid in powershell and it did find it as a node process.